# How to determine if I'm on the first page of pagination?

Tags: pagination, paged, plugin-wp-pagenavi

How do I determine if I'm on the very first page of pagination? I'm using WP_Pagenavi. I want to run a function only on the first page of the pagination. I checked the query_var 'paged', it's set to 0 on this page, and then 2, 3 and so on in the later pages (1 is missing!)... Anyone knows a clean solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
// get current page we are on. If not set we can assume we are on page 1.
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// are we on page one?
if(1 == $paged) {
    //true
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but calling `get_query_var( 'paged' )` twice is redundant.  That function's optional second parameter is the default value.  

So, you could simplify it to:

 `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 ); `

Comment: Aug 2017: This one not working for me, Its outputting 1 on every page.  However Michael's answer worked perfect.

Answer (score 44):

if you only want to know that you're on the first page of a paginated page try [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged):

```
if ( !is_paged() ) {
  // first page of pagination
}
```

Comment: This one worked for me. (Aug 2017). Somehow answer marked as correct not working..

Comment: Excellent, clean and simple.

Comment: not working anymore (Jan 2020)

Comment: @Gangesh it's working just fine. It's a simple WordPress conditional, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_paged/

Comment: Still works | Oct 2023

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a simple way to determine whether or not to use the [`posts_nav_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link) function and all solutions I found online were either too complex or unreliable. For example, many people suggested using the `$paged` global variable, but I found that this variable returned the same value for the first page, even when the first page was the only page!

So, I dug into the `wp-includes/link-template.php` file, and found that the `posts_nav_link()` function simply outputs the return value of another function:

```
/**
 * Display post pages link navigation for previous and next pages.
 *
 * @since 0.71
 *
 * @param string $sep Optional. Separator for posts navigation links.
 * @param string $prelabel Optional. Label for previous pages.
 * @param string $nxtlabel Optional Label for next pages.
 */
function posts_nav_link( $sep = '', $prelabel = '', $nxtlabel = '' ) {
    $args = array_filter( compact('sep', 'prelabel', 'nxtlabel') );
    echo get_posts_nav_link($args);
}
```

Using this knowledge, we can create a simple and effective way to determine whether or not we need to add links to navigate between pages:

```
$posts_nav = get_posts_nav_link();
if(empty($posts_nav)) {
    // do not use posts_nav_link()
} else {
    // use posts_nav_link()
}
```

---

Originally posted on my blog [here](http://igalvez.net/wordpress/checking-when-to-add-links-between-pages/).